# In PRG pattern How to remove ActionMessage on refreshing success page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, post-redirect-get

To avoid the form resubmission I used POST-Redirect-GET pattern and it is working fine. Now on my registration page(success page) it is showing the ActionMessage "Review Inserted successfully!". When user refreshes the page I want to remove this message.

My code on JSP page:

```xml
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <div class="success-mesg" id="success-mesg">
        <s:iterator value="actionMessages">
            <s:property value="top" />
        </s:iterator>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

On struts.xml:

```xml
<action name="insertReview" class = "com.tenkinfo.streamlinedmapnsav.ui.action.WriteReviewAction" method="insertReview" >
    <result name="insertReviewDone" type="redirect" >insertReviewDone</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">display.writeReview.page</result>
</action>

<action name="insertReviewDone" class = "com.tenkinfo.streamlinedmapnsav.ui.action.WriteReviewAction" method="insertReviewDone" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles" >display.writeReview.page</result>
</action>
```

In Action class:

```java
public String insertReviewDone(){
    addActionMessage("Write review is successful");
    return "success";
}
```

**Edit :**

After implementing the answer suggested by Aleksandr M, I am having below problem:

```xml
<s:form name="insertReview" action="insertReview" id="insertReview"
            theme="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="content-area">
            <h1>
            Review
            <s:property value="businessName" />
            </h1>
            <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
            <div class="success-mesg" id="success-mesg">
            <s:iterator value="actionMessages">
        <s:property value="top" />
    </s:iterator>
   </div>
</s:if>
```

After refreshing the page in above code businessName is removed and not displaying.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Store it in session, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Message Store Interceptor`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html) to store action message in your `insertReview` and retrieve it in your `insertReviewDone` action.
Add action message in `insertReview` method when you are returning `insertReviewDone` result.

Also use `redirectAction` result to redirect to action instead of `redirect`.

```
<action name="insertReview" class = "com.tenkinfo.streamlinedmapnsav.ui.action.WriteReviewAction" method="insertReview">
  <interceptor-ref name="store">
    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

  <result name="insertReviewDone" type="redirectAction">insertReviewDone</result>
  <result name="input" type="tiles">display.writeReview.page</result>
</action>

<action name="insertReviewDone" class = "com.tenkinfo.streamlinedmapnsav.ui.action.WriteReviewAction" method="insertReviewDone" >
  <interceptor-ref name="store">
    <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

  <result name="success" type="tiles">display.writeReview.page</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Great! Its what all I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is working fine. But I got a new issue. Editing my question and placing there. I am a newbie so kindly give me some suggestion.

Comment: @user2674752: If you have another issue post a new question.

Comment: But this is related to current problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, less technical than the (good) one proposed by @AleksandrM, but suitable for every framework out there, not only Struts2, is to place this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.history.pushState("","", location.href);
    });
</script>
```

in your `<head>` section. It won't work on old browser with no HTML5 capabilities, though.

Note: jQuery part is not mandatory, it is used just to ensure it is run after the page is loaded, you can run HTML5 `pushState()` without it.

Comment: What it will do? It'll avoid form resubmission or it'll remove success message on refreshing the page?

Comment: I've used it to prevent double form submissions AND double messages, but never with Tiles. Just try, hope that helps.