# How to access one Action class ActionMessages in JSp after another Action class on an Action chain call

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I am trying to implement message store interceptor to show the ActionMessages on my JSp but not able to access the ActionMessages. Could anybody provide a link How to implement Message Store Interceptor?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18914258/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from one of my application  to implement Message Store Interceptor. It has 3 modes:

1. Store: It stores messages in this mode
2. Retrieve: It retrieves messages in this mode
3. Auto: In this mode it does auto-retrieve.

> ```
>   <action name="mailOffer" class = "com.xyz.action.ShareAction" method="mailOffer">
>   <interceptor-ref name="store">
>           <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
>         </interceptor-ref>
>         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
>               <result name="mailOfferDone" type="redirectAction">
>                   <param name="actionName">mailOfferDone</param>
>                   <param name="offerId">${offerId}</param>
>                   <param name="businessName">${businessName}</param>
>                   <param name="businessId">${businessId}</param>
>               </result>
>   </action>
>
> <action name="mailOfferDone" class = "com.xyz.action.ShareAction" method="mailOfferDone">
>   <interceptor-ref name="store">
>       <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
>   </interceptor-ref>
>   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
>   <result name="success" type="tiles">display.share.page</result>
> </action>
> ```